# synchronize drawing of rectangles and scrolling in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scroll, drawing

I am currently working on the cell selection function for a datagridview, I draw rectangles around the cells to simulate the selection, using co-ordinates and size for the rectangle. The problem arises when I scroll down or right to select more cells. While selecting, the rectangles are drawn with the same dimensions and parameters irrespective of which cells are bounded by the rectangle.

I would like to know how do I synchronize my rectangle drawings with the scrolling so as to keep the same cells selected/bounded in the rectangle.

Any help or direction towards this is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what technique you're currently using, but it's worth saying that painting directly onto the `DataGridView` control by handling its `Paint` event is ill-advised.

You will have to break up your painting code into the bounds of specific cells and/or rows and paint in the `CellPainting` or 'RowPostPaint` events. To draw a rectangle around several cells, you could either paint inside the borders of the affected cells, or paint in the adjacent cells.

The `CellBounds` property of `DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs` gives you coordinates that are always relative to the cell itself, which means that it will adapt automatically to scrolling within the `DataGridView`.

**Edit:** An example of how to handle the `CellPainting` event to draw a custom border around a specific cell:

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e) {
    e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, e.PaintParts);
    if ((e.RowIndex == myRowIndex) && (e.ColumnIndex == myColumnIndex)) {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2f);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, e.CellBounds);
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Smith, I shall try that out and see if the scrolling is synchronized. I appreciate your suggestion and seems the right idea to get rid of the scrolling issues

Thanks

Comment: Hi Smith, I wanted to know how do I change the color of a specific border of a cell once I know the row and column index of that cell. Would appreciate if you can guide me.

Comment: The easiest way is to handle the `CellPainting` event, example added to my answer.